# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createInitMintInstruction')

Tags: spl-token, spl, spl-associated-token-account, anchor-spl, createminttoinstruction

I am getting this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createInitMintInstruction')
```

I dont know where and how it went wrong.

Appreciate the help.

```
await program.rpc.mintNft({
    accounts: {
      config,
      candyMachine: candyMachine.id,
      payer: payer,
      wallet: treasury,
      mint: mint.publicKey,
      metadata,
      masterEdition,
      mintAuthority: payer,
      updateAuthority: payer,
      tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
      tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      clock: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
    },
    signers: [mint],
    instructions: [
      anchor.web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer,
        newAccountPubkey: mint.publicKey,
        space: MintLayout.span,
        lamports: rent,
        programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      }),
      Token.createInitMintInstruction(
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        mint.publicKey,
        0,
        payer,
        payer
      ),
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        token,
        payer,
        payer,
        mint.publicKey
      ),
      Token.createMintToInstruction(
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        mint.publicKey,
        token,
        payer,
        [],
        1
      ),
    ],
  });
```

I have imported Token as follows:

> import {
> ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
> MintLayout,
> Token,
> TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
> MINT_SIZE,
> } from "@solana/spl-token";

Comment: If you share the rust side, I could help you.

Comment: Hi Mateo. I am trying to mint a token for Candy Machine V2. And the error is from spl token’s Token class. 

Cmv2 rust: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/candy-machine/program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71284783/18943577

> The latest version of @solana/spl-token exports all the actions that
> were originally on the Token class, giving more flexibility to the
> client.
>
> If you want to use the old Token class, you can do the following:
>
> npm install @solana/spl-token@0.1.8 Otherwise you'll find
> documentation on @solana/spl-token@0.2.0 at the SPL docs and
> Solanacookbook

Thanks Jacob.